# Is there a way to make ReactJs SEO friendly without using Next or Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to make ReactJs SEO friendly without using Next or Gatsby? Because I already made a project and it's difficult to dismantle it to use next or gatsby,
and I just got in trouble when I deployed the project, it's not very SEO friendly.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without using next or gatsby, it is a tedious task to make a pure react based application SEO friendly as it would involve a lot of time as you would have to create an isomorphic app [Isomorphic apps with react](https://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-react-in-real-life), you can also look at this great article for better view [Building search friendly Javascript applications with React.js](https://builtvisible.com/react-js-seo/)

Comment: What about <Helmetprovider><Helmet> script </Helmet></HelmetProvider> ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a previous answer, in order to make a React application SEO-friendly you would have to build an isomorphic application. Currently, the most popular frameworks for developing isomorphic applications are Gatsby and Next.js. This isn’t to say that creating an isomorphic application without them is impossible, but you’re looking at a lot more man-hours. That being said, if you're still struggling to make React SEO-friendly, take a look at this article to get a better understanding of [How to Build Search-Friendly Pages in React](https://buttercms.com/blog/react-seo-how-to-build-search-friendly-pages-in-react).